# Necesito hacer la función en Javascript donde en un input se escriba la primera letra mayúscula y luego minúsculas cada palabra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Buenas noches mi pedido de apoyo es el siguiente, quiero que en el input al escribir las primeras letras sea mayúscula y luego minúsuclas y se repita por cada palabra ejemplo cuando en el input escriba nombres que se vea asi: Jin Star[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Llevas algun avance? Necesitas enviar el dato asi o solo con que se vea asi en el input?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stackoverflow en español @jinstar recuerda que el sitio tiene sus normas, y una de ellas es poner un ejemplo minimo y verificable (código que llevas al momento minimo para reproducir tu problema), sin embargo no se hace evidencia de ello, considera darte un paseo por el [tour] y tambien de paso leer [ask] para que puedas mejorar esta pregunta y las futuras que hagas, saludos.

Comment: De paso también recordar a la comunidad que esta pregunta no es apta para una respuesta por el momento [answer].

Comment: Si sorry, corregido.

Comment: Aqui puedes encontrar la respuesta es basntante sencilla https://baulcode.com/codigos/convertir-texto-a-mayusculas-javascript

Comment: @jinstar debe querer que el input se procese a medida escribes. La respuesta está en añadirle un EventListener "oninput" al input, usar un split que separe su contenido en palabras, que procese cada una, les de el formato establecido, usar un join para unir las palabras en una cadena de texto y por último asignarle ese valor al input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si aun estas buscando

```
function capitalize(str){
 return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
const input = document.getElementById('inputID');
input.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  setTimeout(() => {input.value = capitalize(input.value)}, 1)
})
```

Comment: Hola @AndresGaibor el script funciona perfecto pero tengo un problema; el escript funciona solo la primera letra lo hace en mayúscula y cuando doy espacio y quiero escribir otra palabra la primera palabra se hace minúscula. Ejemplo con el codigo que me diste cuando escribo un nombre se hace asi: Maria jose ; y lo que busco es que sea asi: Maria Jose. También como seria el código si uso 2 input uno que sea de Nombres y otro de Apellidos. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cambia el  `capitalize(input.value).` por `input.value.split(' ').map(x => capitalize(x)).join(' ')`, y si quieres tener mas inputs que hagan lo mismo, siemplente agregale a ese input el mismo addEventListener